# How to force the computer to play another move on Chess.com?

Tags: online-chess

I am playing a game against the computer on chess.com. The computer made a move that looks absurd, so I would like to make it do another move instead and analyse the game.

How to do it?

I tried to share the game with you, but when I hit the "share" button I cannot get a link to that particular moment into the game. Anyway I did Qxd7, Ka8 which is check mate after Qa7. I don't understand why the computer does not want to do Kxb6

[image]

Comment: On what level was the bot on? Sometimes bots make random moves in order to simulate blunders.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the position, you were not playing the strongest computer level. Weaker levels simulate human blunders by deliberately making weaker moves.

Why not just go back a move? There should be an undo button.